# trouble adding hidden description to CSS / JS image gallery

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, gallery

Amateur here. This is my first post.

I've been building on this ["advanced imagery gallery" tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_image_gallery_responsive_js) to add a portfolio of work to my website. I'm also using this opportunity to teach myself more CSS. This is my first time using JV.

BUT IT AINT WORKING.

The tutorial pulls the image description into the modal window and displays it beneath the image using the below.

```
/* Description of Image */
div.desc {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I wanted to explain the piece of work in my portfolio by adding text that displays to the right of the image within the modal only. In an attempt to do this, I created a new div class below

```
/* Caption of Modal Image */
#caption {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    right: 50px;
}
```

And then I specified that it be hidden on the page before activating modal.

```
/* Caption of Image */
div.caption {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: left;
    display: none;
}
```

Down in the body, I have written the below to showcase the work. Problem is, the text does not display when I click on the modal. Originally, this code put a paragraph of description below the image. Once I added "display: none" it disappeared (victory!). But it's still not showing up in the modal window (defeat).

```
<div class="responsive">
  <div class="img">
    <img src="tublr.jpg" alt="tublr" width="300" height="200">
    <div class="desc">The tublr</div>
    <div class="caption">
      <h2><center>The Tublr — tumblr for tubs.</center></h2>
      I created a tumblr for tubs. Post pictures of your favorite tubs, tag your tubs, and share your best tubs with friends. This is the perfect way to network with other tub enthusiasts across the web. Welcome to tublr.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have not TOUCHED the JS part of the tutorial code. It's safe to assume nothing (beyond cosmetic) has been changed in the original tutorial code. Please refer to [that code](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_image_gallery_responsive_js) to fill in any gaps in my explanation — which I hope are not too numerous.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't see any code that would remove your div.caption's `display: none`. Without that code, the caption will never be visible. Where's that code?

Comment: Also, I don't see any element with `id="caption"`, so that `#caption` css is not being used at all.